# Mongoose - How to define 2 types for a field in the Schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

so in my payments model. I have a price field that can either take a payment object (currency, amount) or a "FREE" string. How do I define this in the model.

i.e.

```
price: { currency: "USD", amount: "100.00"}
```

or

```
price: "FREE"
```

So, how to I define this in my model, because this doesn't work:

```
...
price: { currency: String, amount: String } || String
...
```

Comment: Have you looked in to this comment https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/4929#issuecomment-276249592?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [mixed](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#mixed) schema type,

```
new Schema({
ofMixed:    [Schema.Types.Mixed],
})
```

But you have to mark it modified as mentioned in the docs

> Since it is a schema-less type, you can change the value to anything
>   else you like, but Mongoose loses the ability to auto-detect and save
>   those changes. To tell Mongoose that the value of a Mixed type has
>   changed, you need to call doc.markModified(path), passing the path to
>   the Mixed type you just changed.

instead you can use [schema.path()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#path) and look into this [mongoose issue](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/4929#issuecomment-276249592) to get a better solution to avoid `mixed` type here.